# var_dump associative array print NULL

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Complete Array Data:

```
property_status: Sold, Property_ID: lorem ipsum, Available_From: lorem ipsum, Year_Built: lorem ipsum, Exterior_Material: lorem ipsum, Structure_Type: lorem ipsum, AC: lorem ipsum, Acres: lorem ipsum, Bedroom_Features: lorem ipsum, Cross_Streets: lorem ipsum, Dining_Area: lorem ipsum, Disability_Access: lorem ipsum, Entry_Location: lorem ipsum, Exterior_Cnstruction: lorem ipsum, Fireplace_Fuel: lorem ipsum, Fireplace_Location: lorem ipsum, Legal_Desc: lorem ipsum, Lot_Description: lorem ipsum, Lot_Size_Source: lorem ipsum, Misc_Interior: lorem ipsum, Sewer: lorem ipsum, Source_Of_Sqft: lorem ipsum, Terms: lorem ipsum, View_Desc: lorem ipsum, address: 129-133 West 22nd Street, local-area: Shoreditch, latitude: 40.7427704, longitude: -73.99455039999998, city: Bretagne, postcode: 10011, country: USA, phone: 212245-4606, fax: 212245-4606, contact-email: test@test.com, contact_web: e-plugin.com, listing_contact_source: new_value, youtube: 0y4rXoWrJlw, facebook: test, linkedin: test, twitter: test, instagram: test, youtube_social: test, bedrooms: 4, bathrooms: 3, guest: 1, garages: 2, sale_or_rent_price: 5210641, price_postfix_text: $, area: 6000, area_postfix_text: SFT, rent_period: , _favorites: , , 1, _edit_lock: 1632717839:1, _edit_last: 1, _public_facilities: a:3:{s:4:"Shop";s:0:"";s:7:"Airport";s:1:"8";s:11:"City center";s:1:"4";}, state: , image_gallery_ids: ,4290,4289, contact_name: , vimeo: , rs_page_bg_color: , site-sidebar-layout: default, site-content-layout: default, theme-transparent-header-meta: default, stick-header-meta: default, realpro_featured: featured, offer: s:94:"a:3:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Sanad Qazi";s:5:"email";s:14:"test@sanad.com";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";}";, _plan_description_0:
```

How fetching data:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
$id = $post->ID;

$custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);
            
var_dump($custom_fields);
```

Output:

```
array(67) { ["property_status"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Sold" } ["Property_ID"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Available_From"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Year_Built"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Exterior_Material"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Structure_Type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["AC"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Acres"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Bedroom_Features"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Cross_Streets"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Dining_Area"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Disability_Access"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Entry_Location"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Exterior_Cnstruction"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Fireplace_Fuel"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Fireplace_Location"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Legal_Desc"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Lot_Description"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Lot_Size_Source"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Misc_Interior"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Sewer"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Source_Of_Sqft"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["Terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["View_Desc"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "lorem ipsum" } ["address"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "129-133 West 22nd Street" } ["local-area"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Shoreditch" } ["latitude"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "40.7427704" } ["longitude"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "-73.99455039999998" } ["city"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Bretagne" } ["postcode"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10011" } ["country"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "USA" } ["phone"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "212245-4606" } ["fax"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "212245-4606" } ["contact-email"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "test@test.com" } ["contact_web"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "e-plugin.com" } ["listing_contact_source"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "new_value" } ["youtube"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "0y4rXoWrJlw" } ["facebook"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "test" } ["linkedin"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "test" } ["twitter"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "test" } ["instagram"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "test" } ["youtube_social"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "test" } ["bedrooms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } ["bathrooms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } ["guest"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["garages"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } ["sale_or_rent_price"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "5210641" } ["price_postfix_text"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "$" } ["area"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "6000" } ["area_postfix_text"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "SFT" } ["rent_period"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["_favorites"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) ", , 1" } ["_edit_lock"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "1632717800:1" } ["_edit_last"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["_public_facilities"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(73) "a:3:{s:4:"Shop";s:0:"";s:7:"Airport";s:1:"8";s:11:"City center";s:1:"4";}" } ["state"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["image_gallery_ids"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) ",4290,4289" } ["contact_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["vimeo"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["rs_page_bg_color"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["site-sidebar-layout"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "default" } ["site-content-layout"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "default" } ["theme-transparent-header-meta"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "default" } ["stick-header-meta"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "default" } ["realpro_featured"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "featured" } ["offer"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(102) "s:94:"a:3:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Sanad Qazi";s:5:"email";s:14:"test@sanad.com";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";}";" } ["_plan_description_0"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Added one more line in code just to fetch 'Offer' array:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
$id = $post->ID;

$custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['offer'];
            
var_dump($my_custom_field);
```

Output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(102) "s:94:"a:3:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Sanad Qazi";s:5:"email";s:14:"test@sanad.com";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";}";" }
```

Now I am trying to only display value of email but nothing is getting printed, why?

Code I tried:

```
global $post;
$post = $wp_query->post;
$id = $post->ID;

$custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['offer'];
            
var_dump($my_custom_field['email']);
```

Output: `NULL`

Tried with foreach loop:

```
global $post;
$post = $wp_query->post;
$id = $post->ID;

$custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['offer'];
            
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
      var_dump( $value ['email'] ) . "<br>";
  }
```

Output: `string(1) "s"`

I wanted to display the value of email only, any help appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `unserialize()`.

Comment: unserialize() returning boolean value 'false'

Comment: What is the actual code you try to use `unserialize` with ?

Comment: `unserialize(base64_decode($my_custom_field));`

also without base64_decode, still same result

Comment: As the field is an array - try `unserialize($my_custom_field[0]);`

Comment: Thanks allot man, this helped me `unserialize(base64_decode($my_custom_field[0]));`
Much appriciated.

Comment: When I tried same thing with foreach loop, again getting same Boolean false return

foreach($my_custom_field as $results){   
$result = unserialize(base64_decode($results[0]));

   var_dump($result);
}